# Ruby on Rails Model.create function doesn't store a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function that calls a few things one after the other (including reading a JSON doc) and creates a few entries in a database.
I have a model "Entry" and a nested model "Subentry". The code works like this:

```
...
new_entry = add_entry(param1, param2)
sub_entries = json_doc[:subentries]
sub_entries.each do |se|
  add_sub_entry(param1, new_entry)
end
...
```

The function add_entry is very simple:

```
def add_entry(param1, param2)
  store_entry = {}
  store_entry[:param1] = param1
  store_entry[:param2] = param2
  return Entry.create(store_entry)
end
```

And the function add_subentry is similar:

```
def add_subentry(param1, entry)
  store_sub_entry = {}
  store_sub_entry[:param1] = param1
  entry.subentries.create(store_sub_entry)
end
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error (from the second function, add_subentry):

```
You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
```

when I manually run the first function in the Rails console, the Entry is saved. When I inspect what happens while running the code (threw in a byebug), "new_entry" indeed is not saved at the point where the add_sub_entry function is called. I don't understand why?

Comment: It's possible there is a validation error while trying to create the Entry object... If you temporarily replace `Entry.create` with `Entry.create!` it will raise an error if Entry record is not saved which may point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks - there was indeed a problem with a parameter that didn't work properly and the error raised was very explicit :)